# Issues with char and string assignments on C (integer from pointer without a cast?)

Tags: c, string, variables, char, declaration

I've made the following declarations on my code:

```
char bussola, com[1], pen;
int main()
{
   bussola = "oeste", pen = "up";
```

but for some reason I'm getting this error on the compiler:

```
 main.c:18:10: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 
 bussola = "oeste", pen = "up";
           ^             ^
```

And because of that I keep getting other errors like this one:

```
main.c:51:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
 
 if (bussola == "oeste") 
              ^~
```

What should I do?

Comment: `bussola` is a `char`.  `"oeste"` is a _string literal_.  Do you want `bussola` as a single `char` or maybe as `char *bussola` so it is a pointer to `char`s?

Comment: I hate to say "RTFM", but these folks are right.  You can't easily guess your way through learning C; it's just too esoteric.  There's a lot tutorials for operating against strings in C online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char bussola[6], pen[3];

int main() {
   strcpy(bussola, "oeste");
   strcpy(pen, "up");
}
```

```
if(!strcmp(bussola,"oeste")
```

This above is the correct syntax for what you are trying to do.

Considering this code, I would suggest to thorough the strings and character concepts in C and also the `string.h` header file functions.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning a char array (AKA string) to a char variable, they aren't compatible data types.
A char variable can only have single char values (like 'a' , 'F', '2' or ' '). Its important to use single quotes (' ') to interpret the character like a char variable.
You can declare a string using char * bussola or char bussola[LENGTH], but you will have to initialize the array in the declaration:

```
char bussola[6] = "oeste";
```

if you want to initialize it later, you can use strcpy:

```
char bussola[6];
strncpy(bussola, "oeste", 6);
```

Be aware that string use double quotes (" ") instead of single quotes like chars.